# How can I access a service installed on Kubernetes from anywhere?

Tags: java, kubernetes, microservices, devops

I am working on a mac machine and installed the latest Kubernetes and followed the [example here](https://medium.com/@claudiopro/getting-started-with-kubernetes-via-minikube-ada8c7a29620#.xfrpcgv50) (this is for dev’t purpose). All went smooth but I was hoping that Kubernetes provide me an ip address and port number where my service will be listening to so that I can access it from anywhere.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

I was able to run `ifconfig` as well as `curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)` and I was able to see the ip address and port but I wasn’t able to access it outside command line where Kubernetes lives in.

The reason I am trying to access it outside the VM is because we have other projects that run on other machines and I wanted to call the REST service I installed while we are on dev env. This way we don’t have to wait until the service is pushed to production.

FYI: This is my first micro service project and I would appericiate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps in the article you linked and it works as expected.

Just do:

```
minikube service hello-minikube --url
```

You will get a url like `http://192.168.99.100:32382/` - the port and IP could and will change for you. Also note that the exposed port will be a random port like the `32382` and not `8080` that the pod uses.

Use the url in your browser, say and you should be able to see the output of the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still need a clarification on the ip. My assumption is the service lives in the virtual box so when I use "curl <ip address>" on command line and when I type the ip in my browser it works without any problem. When this ip is exposed, I thought it can be accessed from anywhere so I tried accessing the ip address from my phone and other places and it didnt work. So does that mean the ip is only accessible from my machine ? How does that makes it public ?

Comment: @WowBow minikube is about running a local kubernetes cluster. Making a service public is making it accessible to the outside world, which in this case, is your dev box.

Comment: @WowBow - `kubectl port-forward` should help, but there is this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29678

Comment: Now I get it. I never thought the "outside world" means only my dev box.

Comment: Can you please review my edits and approve it so that I can accept the answer ?